# CSS transition isn't working

Tags: css

I am trying to get the submenu in the navigation bar appear with a transition. But this isn't working. The css code I am using is this-

```
#navigation li ul {
   display: none; 
   width: auto;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: #F87217;
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: 0.7s;
    -o-transition: 0.7s;
    transition: 0.7s;   
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

How can I get the transition working?

Comment: You can't transition `display`. Try transitioning `height` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't transition `display`. Try transitioning `height` or `opacity` instead:

```
#navigation li ul {
   display: block; 
   width: auto;
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0; /* optional */
   /* other attributes */
    -webkit-transition: 0.7s;
    -moz-transition: 0.7s;
    -o-transition: 0.7s;
    transition: 0.7s;   
}

#navigation li:hover ul {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1; /* optional */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use display none, the item is not rendered... So you will never be able to hover it. Usging height as [Jan Dvorak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499214/jan-dvorak) says might be a better option. But also an item with height 0 can't be hovered.

I'd recommend using transparency.

```
#navigation li ul {
opacity: 0;
...
}
#navigation li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: note the parent is hovered, not the element that's being hidden.

Comment: Oops, missed that... You are right, then it depends on wheter you want a sliding or a fading effect :)